# How to get the list of files that are not in another directory in perl

Tags: perl

I have to fix a Perl script, which does the following:

```
# Get the list of files in the staging directory; skip all beginning with '.'
opendir ERR_STAGING_DIR, "$ERR_STAGING" or die "$PID: Cannot open directory $ERR_STAGING";
@allfiles = grep !/^$ERR_STAGING\/\./, map "$ERR_STAGING/$_", readdir(ERR_STAGING_DIR);
closedir(ERR_STAGING_DIR);
```

I have two directories one is `STAGING` and other is `ERROR`.  STAGING contains files like `ABC_201608100000.fin` and `ERR_STAGING_DIR` contains `ABC_201608100000.fin.bc_lerr.xml`. Now the Perl script is run as a daemon process which constantly looks for the files in `ERR_STAGING_DIR` directory and processes the error files.

However, my requirement is to do not process the file if `ABC_201608100000.fin` exists in STAGING.

#### Question:

Is there a way , I can filter the `allfiles` array and select files which don't exist in STAGING directory?

#### WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

I have done programmatic way to ignore the files that exist in STAGING dir. Though it is not working.

```
     # Move file from the staging directory to the processing directory.
        @splitf = split(/.bc_lerr.xml/,basename($file));
        my $finFile = $STAGING . "/" . $splitf[0];
        print LOG "$PID: Staging File $finFile \n";

        foreach $file(@sorted_allfiles) {    
        if ( -e $finFile )
        {
            print LOG "$PID: Staging File still exist.. moving to next $finFile \n";
            next;
        }
        # DO THE PROCESSING.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions of timing aside, I assume that a snapshot of files may be processed without worrying about new files showing up. I take it that `@allfiles` has all file names from the `ERROR` directory.

Remove a file name from the front of the array at each iteration. Check for the corresponding file in `STAGING` and if it's not there process away, otherwise push it on the back of the array and skip.

```
while (@allfiles) 
{
     my $errfile = shift @allfiles;

     my ($file) = $errfile =~ /(.*)\.bc_lerr\.xml$/;

     if (-e "$STAGING/$file")
     {
          push @allfiles, $errfile;
          sleep 1;                    # more time for existing files to clear
          next;
     }
     # process the error file
}
```

If the processing is faster than what it takes for existing files in `STAGING` to go away, we would exhaust all processable files and then continuously run file tests. There is no reason for such abuse of resources, thus the `sleep`, to give `STAGING` files some more time to go away. Note that if just one file in `STAGING` fails to go away this loop will keep checking it and you want to add some guard against that.

Another way would be to process the error files with a `foreach`, and add those that should be skipped to a separate array. That can then be attempted separately, perhaps with a suitable wait.

How suitable this is depends on details of the whole process. For how long do `STAGING` files hang around, and is this typical or exceptional? How often do new files show up? How many files are there typically?

---

If you only wish to filter out the error files that have their counterparts in `STAGING`

```
my @errfiles_nostaging = grep { 
    my ($file) = $_ =~ /(.*)\.bc_lerr\.xml$/;
    not -e "$STAGING/$file";
} @allfiles;
```

The output array contains the files from `@allfiles` which have no corresponding file in `$STAGING` and can be readily processed. This would be suitable if the error files are processed very fast in comparison to how long the `$STAGING` files stay around.

The filter can be written in one statement as well.  For example

```
grep { not -e "$STAGING/" . s/\.bc_lerr\.xml$//r }              # / or
grep { not -e "$STAGING/" . (split /\.bc_lerr\.xml$/, $_)[0] }
```

The first example uses the *non-destructive* `/r` modifier, available [since 5.14](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/pod/perl5140delta.pod#Non-destructive_substitution). It changes the substitution to *return* the changed string and *not change* the original one. See it [`in perlrequick`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace) and [`in perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2f_PATTERN_%2f_REPLACEMENT_%2f_msixpodualngcer).

Comment: @user2570205 This answer is a first take, since I don't know any of the relevant details of your whole problem.  If you provide feedback or additional requirements or explanations, I can adjust it.

Comment: Is there a way we filter in the grep statement ?

Comment: @user2570205  Yes -- added to the end of the answer.  If you need it one statement let me know.  If I should explain how it works, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely brute force example, but if you have the contents of the staging directory in an array, you can check against that array when you read the contents of the error directory.

I've made some GIGANTIC assumptions about the relationship of the filenames -- basically that the stage directory contains the file truncated, specifically the way you listed in your example.  If that's universally the case, then a substring would work even faster, but this example is a little more scalable, in the event your example was simplified to illustrate the issue.

```
use strict;

my @error = qw(
  ABC_201608100000.fin.bc_lerr.xml
  ABD_201608100000.fin.bc_lerr.xml
  ABE_201608100000.fin.bc_lerr.xml
  ABF_201608100000.fin.bc_lerr.xml
);

my @staging = qw(
  ABC_201608100000.fin
  ABD_201608100000.fin
);

foreach my $error (@error) {
  my $stage = $error;
  $stage =~ s/\.bc_lerr\.xml//;

  unless (grep { /$stage/ } @staging) {
     ## process the file here
  }
}
```

The `grep` in this example is O(n), so if you have a really large list of either array you would want to load this into a hash first, which would be O(1).